# go build vs go build file.go

Tags: compiler-construction, build, go

What's the difference between `go build` and `go build file.go`?

I'm asking because when I run `go build` on a package that imports a local package, then I get this error message.

`can't load package: C:\go\src\bug\main.go:3:8: local import "./local_file" in non-local package`

However, when I specify a file name it works. Ex `go build main.go`

Console history on Windows XP.

```
C:\gopath\src\bug:>go version
go version go1.1 windows/386
C:\gopath\src\bug:>dir
...
<DIR>          local_file
                55 main.go
...

C:\gopath\src\bug:>type main.go
package main

import _ "./local_file"

func main() {
}

C:\gopath\src\bug:>type local_file\local_file.go
package local_file

import "fmt"

func init() {
        fmt.Println("Called: local_file.init()")
}

C:\gopath\src\bug:>go run main.go
Called: local_file.init()

C:\gopath\src\bug:>go build main.go

C:\gopath\src\bug:>dir
...
<DIR>          local_file
         1,285,120 main.exe
                55 main.go  
...

C:\gopath\src\bug:>go build
can't load package: C:\gopath\src\bug\main.go:3:8: local import "./local_file" in non-local package
```

Comment: Where should `go build` install package local_file to?

Comment: Anywhere but why would the package `local_file` need to be installed to create an executable? Shouldn't the compiler just reference it locally?

Answer (score 9):

I asked this question on the google group site for golang and here's one of the responses.

> `go build file.go` (even if `file.go` is in `GOPATH`) isn't building a
>   package in a workspace, so it follows doesn't follow that rule. The
>   downside is that you have to name all the `*.go` files, you don't get
>   some of the automatic behaviour of the `go` command (eg: testing &
>   installing), and you can't build a package (which requires
>   installing), only executables. Also, it's not go-gettable.
>
> The "`go build file.go`" should only ever be used for simple one source
>   file binaries that you don't intend to ever distribute or re-use code
>   from. Even then, it's often simpler and faster to follow the go tool's
>   conventions: one package per folder (and vice versa) no relative
>   imports (ever) "`go run file.go`" follows the same logic, and is even
>   less recommended.
>
> Both patterns are meant for very specific uses, and should be avoided
>   in regular programs and packages.
>
> By: [Carlos Castillo](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/V-8aaONKkmc)

So it turns out that Google Go enforces the import path for packages to be relative to the `src` directory in the environmental variables `GOROOT` or `GOPATH`.

Thus here's the fix to make the program build with `go build`.

Note: `GOPATH` is set to `C:\gopath`

Change `main.go` from

```
package main

import _ "./local_file"

func main() {
}
```

To this

```
package main

import _ "bug/local_file"

func main() {
}
```