# Does it make sense to have two packages in the same directory?

Tags: go, package

I have a project that provides a library (exports some funcs) and also must provide a command-line interface (there must be an executable file).

Example of directory structure:

```
whatever.io/
    myproject/
        main.go
        myproject.go
```

The go compiler needs the *package main* and *func main* to start execution. My library needs the *package myproject* where I put stuff on it. This is what the go tool says when I am building another project that tries to import myproject:

```
main.go:5:2: found packages myproject (myproject.go) and main (main.go) in $GOPATH/src/whatever.io/myproject
```

So I believe there is no way to do it.

Should I move the library or the CLI to another package?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just move your packages inside a new folder within the same directory of main.go.
Remember to import the new package from the reference of the $GOPATH.

Example:

```
user@user:~/p/go/test/so-multipack$ ls -R
.:
a  main.go

./a:
a.go
user@user:~/p/go/test/so-multipack$ cat main.go 
package main

import (
    "../so-multipack/a"
)
func main(){
    a.Hello()
}
user@user:~/p/go/test/so-multipack$ cat a/a.go 
package a
import (
    "fmt"
)
func Hello(){
    fmt.Println("hello from a")
}
user@user:~/p/go/test/so-multipack$ go run main.go 
hello from a
user@user:~/p/go/test/so-multipack$ go build 
user@user:~/p/go/test/so-multipack$ ls
a  main.go  so-multipack
user@user:~/p/go/test/so-multipack$
```

Useful link:

[go build vs go build file.go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234445/go-build-vs-go-build-file-go/19240125#19240125)

Comment: @xrash, but please consider changing the import in the code of your command to `whatever.io/myproject` -- do not use relative imports (see, [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10687627/720999), for one example, and the pointers it contains).

Comment: Relative paths are ok only if the each package is within their own directory and are referenced from the GOPATH. Otherwise `go build` might fail.

Comment: It sounds so easy so simple... yet not when you take somebody's .proto files for example and try to build GO files :\

Answer (score 31):

You cannot have two packages per directory, hence the error. So the solution as @Larry Battle said to move your `myproject.go` to a new directory.

From [How to write go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#PackagePaths)

> Go code must be kept inside a workspace. A workspace is a directory
>   hierarchy with three directories at its root:
>
> **src contains Go source files organized into packages (one package per directory),**
>
> pkg contains package objects, and
>
> bin contains executable commands.

Comment: There is an exception https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/time/example_test.go

Comment: the link you refer has removed statement "(one package per directory)"

Comment: @yuxh: at Overview section "Each package consists of one or more Go source files in a single directory."

Answer (score 23):

In most cases, **no**. However, there is an **exception for unit tests**.

### Working Example:

Here are 2 different packages (`mypackage` and `mypackage_test`) in 1 directory (`mypackage`). The compiler will not complain about this.

**mypackage folder:**

```
mypackage/
  foo.go
  foo_test.go
```

**mypackage/foo.go:**

```
package mypackage

func Add(a int, b int) int {
    return a + b
}
```

**mypackage/foo_test.go:**

```
package mypackage_test

// Unit tests...
```

### Rules:

1. The 2 packages must have the following names:

- NameOfPackage
- NameOfPackage + `_test`

2. The names of the files in the `_test` package must end with `_test.go`

If you're receiving a confusing compiler error along the lines of `found packages "foo" and "bar"`, you've probably broken one or more of these rules.

To clarify rule 1: it is idiomatic for packages (other than `main`) to have the same name as the directory that contains the files for that directory. But this is not actually a rule that Go's compiler or runtime enforces.

Comment: unittest "package" code is not compiled into the non-unittest package code. So there is no packaging conflict.

Comment: But Go Testing says - To write a new test suite, create a file whose name ends _test.go that contains the ) functions as described here. Put the file in the same package as the one being tested.

Comment: @AananthK The documentation is slightly outdated; it's missing some information about the `_test` package idiom. Here is a [github issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25223) discussing the piece of documentation you quoted.

Comment: Thanks for the info @byxor

Answer (score 8):

You can't have two golang files in one directory with two packages. So you need to move `main.go` out of `myproject`.

the directory structure before move

```
whatever.io/
    go.mod
    myproject/
        main.go
        myproject.go
```

After move

```
whatever.io/
    go.mod
    main.go
    myproject/
        myproject.go
```

And you need to change your `main.go`'s import path. If the module name is `aaa`

Before

```
import "aaa"
```

Need change to this

```
import "aaa/myproject"
```

Comment: how would this work with env files though. When locally i can ../.env but when i deploy the .env is at the root level. So that's an issue