# undefined main - testing code unable to acess main package

Tags: go

In the below code:

## ../folder1/some_test.go

```
package main_test

import "testing"

func TestF(t *testing.T) {
    main.F()
}
```

---

## ../folder1/some_file.go

```
package main

func F() {

}
```

---

`main.F()` gives `undefined main`

```
$ go version
go version go1.14.3 linux/amd64
```

Renaming package name from `main_test` to `main` resolve the problem.

Why `main_test` package name is not allowed for testing code, in same folder?

Answer (score 0):

You must import the package to use the package.

go.mod:

```
module example.app
```

main.go:

```
package main

func F() {}

func main() {}
```

main_test.go

```
package main_test

import (
    "testing"
    "example.app"  // import the main package
)

func TestF(t *testing.T) {
    main.F()
}
```

The code above assumes that main*.go are in the same directory as go.mod for package `example.app`. Replace `example.app` with the name of your module. Adjust the paths to match your application.  For example, if the the main*.go files are in the directory `cmd/example` below the directory containing go.mod, use the import path `example.app/cmd/example` instead of `example.app`.

Note that a test can import a [main package](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution) this way, but non-test code cannot.

Answer (score -3):

The problem is that `main_test` is a different package from `main`.

To access functions in `main` you need to import `main` and access the functions like this: `main.F()`

Also, note `f` starts with lowercase and thus is not exported from the package `main`. To access it in `main_test` it needs to be exported (which can be done by changing it to start with a capital letter: `F`).

Alternatively, you can change the test file to be in package `main`.

Edit with a note: When importing `main` note that import paths are by directory name. Usually developers in Go put their packages in directories with the same name as the package (e.g. put `main` in a directory named `main`). In your case the package and directory names are different so the import will be `import ".../folder1"` not `import ".../main"`. You'll still be able to use `main.F()` to access the function:

```
package main_test

import (
   "testing"
   "../folder1" // use the full path to folder1 from the root of your module
)

func TestF(t *testing.T) {
    main.F()
}
```

Comment: I changed it to `F()` I still see the same error. Query edited

Comment: Are you importing `main`?

Comment: If I import `main` then it gives error for line `package main_test` now with error `can't load package: package main:`

Comment: Running command `go test some_test.go`  from folder `../folder1` and the error is: `imports main: cannot find package "main" in any of` GOROOT, GOPATH

Comment: Looks like your import path is wrong. If you're using Go modules, import main using the path starting with the root directory of your module. If not, import it with the file path from $GOPATH/src

Comment: For example, if your project's root dir is "myproject" and the package `main` is in "folder1" you can import it like `import "myproject/folder1"` in which case you will still do `main.F()`.

Comment: `some_test.go` works with `package main` without any error

Comment: That makes sense - because now it is in the same package as `F` so no importing is needed.

Comment: But Go allows `packagename_test` package name in same folder, Isn't it?

Comment: That is correct. But, even though it's in the same directory, it is a different package. And thus `main` needs to be imported. Also, just to add - import statements are by directory name not package name so I think an issue with your import might have been importing `main` instead of the directory in which `main` is located. Usually developers name their directory the same as the package contained in it, but from your post it appears the dir is not named `main` for you.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55105170/3317808) does not import, but yes, package name is same as folder

Comment: I should mention `main "github.com/myhub/folder1"`. this works

Comment: That example doesn't show any tests just the package name. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998250/proper-package-naming-for-testing-with-the-go-language/31443271#31443271)